# PixiJS v4 - Maintaining Graphic Size on Transform

Tags: pixi.js

First things first...  I am a GIS Developer trying to leverage PixiJS WebGL capabilities to draw data client side.  I am just dipping my toes into client side graphics, so please forgive any mis-wording(s) in this post.

I have successfully been drawing features on my map with PixiJS (using graphics).  But when I change zoom levels, those graphics grow/shrink in size.  I would like them to stay the same.  For example, I am calling drawRect with a width/height of 7 pixels.  As I zoom in/out, I expect those rectangles to maintain that size, but they don't.  Hopefully the image at the bottom makes my issue clear to understand.

Here is how I am drawing graphics:

```
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
for (var i = 0; i < featureCollection.features.length; i++) {
    var feature = featureCollection.features[i];
    if (feature.geometry.type == "Point") {
        var screenPoint = this.olMap.getPixelFromCoordinate(
            proj.fromLonLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        );
        graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x0000ff, 1);
        graphics.beginFill(0xff700b, 1);
        graphics.drawRect(screenPoint[0], screenPoint[1], 7, 7);
    }
}
this.pixiContainer.addChild(graphics);
this.pixiRenderer.render(this.stage);
```

And then when the map changes zoom levels, this is how I am updating the container.  I am leaving out the computation of divTopLeft and diff variables as its a bit verbose.

```
this.pixiContainer.setTransform(divTopLeft[0], divTopLeft[1], diff, diff);
this.pixiRenderer.render(this.pixiContainer);
```

[image]

Comment: Wondered about this as well. How do you place graphics that’s change position but not their scale when parent container is rescaling?

Answer (score 3):

If the scale of a PixiJS DisplayObject (your pixiContainer) is changed, e. g. `this.pixiContainer.scale.set(4, 4)` all the children in the container are scaled too.

If you want the child elements to keep their absolute size, they have to be scaled in opposite direction:

```
for (let child of this.pixiContainer.children) {
    child.scale.set(1 / 4, 1 / 4)
}
```